# The ExcelPackage object does not return sheets

Tags: excel, blazor, epplus

I am trying to upload an excel file to a hosted Blazor webassembly application, for which I am using the following code:

```
string path= @"D:\Otros\LibrosExcel\ReferenciasDotación.xls";

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
    //loop all worksheets
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
    //loop all rows
    for (int i = 1; i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
    {
        //loop all columns in a row
        for (int j = 1; j <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; j++)
        {
            //add the cell data to the List
            if (worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null)
            {
                excelData.Add(worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
return excelData;
```

but the line of code

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault ();
```

returns `null`

Comment: Tested your code. It works fine. At least with EPPlus v4 in asp.net